alignment error when adding error bars to barplot in ggplot
i can't get the error bars to align with the corresponding bar.
i have tried adjusting the width, using position_dodge and position_dodge2, and saying position = "dodge". i am not familiar with the position/position_dodge functions though, so maybe i had an error. see code and image for details
ggplot(axon_data, aes(x=dose, y=length, fill = hour)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= length-sd, ymax=length+sd), 
    width = 0.2, 
    position = position_dodge2())

enter image description here

Welcome to SO! Try with position_dodge2(width = 0.9) for your error bars too, to dodge them by the same amount as the bars. For more help please provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.
